# cakephp3 Users pluginのインストールについて

Tags: php, cakephp

xampp環境でcakephp3のUsers pluginをインストールしようとしていますが、いまいちインストール方法を理解しておりません。
https://www.cakedc.com/jorge_gonzalez/2015/09/23/cakedc_users_plugin_for_cakephp_3
を参考にしましたが**composer require cakedc/users:~3.1.0**はどのフォルダをで実行するのでしょうか。
composer実行後vendorフォルダにいくつかのフォルダとファイルが出来ましたがpluginsフォルダは何も入っていなかったので以下の手順でインストールをしました。

①composer実行後vendor\cakedc\usersをpluginsへコピー
②bootstrap.phpに以下を追加
Plugin::load('CakeDC/Users', ['routes' => true, 'bootstrap' => true]);
③cake migrations migrate -p CakeDC/UsersでUsersテーブルを作成
④cake users addSuperuserを実行
⑤Controller/AppController.phpのinitializeに
$this->loadComponent('CakeDC/Users.UsersAuth');を追加

この後cakephpを実行するとCakeDC/Users.UsersAuthComponent could not be found.となってしまいます。

どなたかインストール手順を教えていただけないでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`composer require cakedc/users` は、アプリケーションディレクトリ（src, webrootなどがあるディレクトリ）で実行します。

CakePHP3以降はプラグインの呼び出しは`vendor/`配下からも行えるようになっているため、①の手順は不要です。②以降の手順はそのままでよいでしょう。

また、CakePHP本体のバージョンはいくつでしょうか。
最新版は3.3.12ですので、CakeDC/Usersのバージョンもそれに合わせて変更する必要があります。
https://github.com/CakeDC/users#versions-and-branches

対応するバージョンがわからない場合は、1行目のようにバージョン指定なしでcomposer requireを実行してください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。無事に起動できました。composerの使用箇所が悪かったようです。